# Definition of "Electric current intensity" for a spatially distributed conductor(Will it transform to some sort of "Current flux"?)

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics, definition

Assume a long linearly distributed conducting body which its height and width isn't comparable to its length. In classical theory of electromagnetism we can deduce most of the charges/electrons approximately move in a line along the length of the body with a speed which is named "Drift velocity" and most of other random motions such as thermal motions cancel each other and are negligible. On the other hand since the body is almost distributed linearly we assume that in the most of the path taken by the electrons the cross sectional area passed by them are the same and therefore constant. So with keeping these assumptions in mind we can easily define "Electric current intensity" as "the number of electrons passed over any identical cross sections of a uniform linearly distributed body per unit time":
$$I:=\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
But when it comes to conducting bodies with spatially distributed charges this definition seems completely useless since the speed of charges/electrons aren't necessarily in one direction and also the cross sectional area passed by the charges will differ from time to time.

**Now the question is:**

What is the definition of "Electric current intensity" in a "Spatially distributed conductor"? Will the definition transform to some kind of "Electric current flux"?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [current density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you. That really helped. I don't know how I forgot when it comes to bodies with distributions in space or plane we turn to using infinitesimal surface elements and volume elements. Now it made sense. Just two more thing: 1)Is the angle of passage of the charges through the surface element taken into account in the definition of current intensity? Or is it even important?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  2)Is it possible to build spatial electrical networks which obey some laws similar to electrical laws in the "Circuit theory" that we discussed in [an earlier question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294590/126696)?